# Converting serialized data to dictionary in django

Tags: python, django

I tried to serialize user data in Django but then I wanted to print it in the console as a dictionary, it was giving me an empty dictionary, how would I go about this.

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from accounts.models import User



class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import  ListAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serialize import UserSerializer




import json



class userApi(ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)

apiuser=userApi()
point = json.dumps(apiuser.__dict__)


print(point)
```

console

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
[2020-11-02 15:45:50,086] autoreload: INFO - Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

**{}**#This is what it is printing
```

Any help guys

Answer (score 0):

Serializers returns dictionary by default, so if you want to print serialized data on the console, you must print it in the `get` method of view. something like this:

```
class userApi(ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        print(serializer_class.data)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

And set a url for the view like this:

```
path('users/', userApi.as_view())
```

And when you open this url in browser or send a get request to it, the serialized data is printed in console.